# Querying my Eve API from my Flask code

Tags: python, flask, eve

In Flask, I have an Eve API running under endpoints like /api/v1/Widgets

I can query that from e.g. Javascript, but I don't know how to *properly* query that API from elsewhere within my Flask app.

Just now for example, if I need to search Widgets in one of my routes, then I'm loading the `requests` module and querying the API using a separate http request, and dealing with the JSON returned.

```
@app.route('/hello')
def show_hello():
    resp   = requests.get('http://example.com/api/v1/Widgets')
    return jsonify({'results': resp.json()})
```

That's surely very inefficient and it seems like there must be something like

```
my_endpoint = app.Eve.endpoint('Widgets')          # not real
return jsonify({'results': my_endpoint.search()})  # not real
```

But I don't know what that is. Could someone help me understand if/how I can make queries directly into my Eve endpoints from with my normal Flask app routes?

Comment: Don't request from the API; just define a function that's returned both when '/hello' is called and anywhere else you might use it within your flask application.

Comment: I want to create records using my Eve endpoint, the equivalent of POSTing in a new record, e.g. to get the extra variables etc.. I thought it would be an attribute of the app, or the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `app.test_client.get()` which is however rate limited, authenticated and raises pre-request events.

With v0.7 (currently on the [`develop` branch](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve)) you can use [`get_internal`](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/methods/get.py#L42). This method is not rate limited, authentication is not checked and pre-request events are not raised. Usage example:

```
from eve.methods.get import get_internal

payload = get_internal(endpoint)
```